# Why ASP.NET CheckedChanged not fired?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

I've a HTML Table with CheckBox in each cell.
My first row below my Header cell have a problem, when I check it, the Event is correctly fired but when I uncheck it, there are no event. The other cell and Checkbox work correctly (Check/Uncheck with event). When I did not create the Header Cells work correctly.

See my cells don't work uncheked event:

[image]

My Code Behind :

http://pastebin.com/sEmkhVRP

(The syntax of variables is imposed on me)

Comment: Can you show us the aspx code as well as code-behind(C# or VB) area?

Comment: Post your ASPX and Code behind so we can see what the issue is. You are making this too hard for anyone to answer or help you.

Comment: I've re-try and when I remove the header in my table, the events work correctly... Why when I add header in my table my events for the first row below my header don't work ? 
Looking for several days and I can not find solutions. The debugger shows me that I did not enter the event and nothing action are doing in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, use a TableHeaderRow and add it TableHeaderCell. I've only use TableHeaderCell and doesn't work.

In ASPX :

```
                       <asp:Table ID="InfosTable" CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped"
                                runat="server" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0">
                                <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow1" runat="server" ForeColor="Snow" BackColor="OliveDrab"
                                    Font-Bold="true">

                                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                            </asp:Table>
```

And in Code behind you can use :

```
    tblheaderCell = New TableHeaderCell
                tblheaderCell.Text = " Liste " & candidat.CAN_Liste

                TableHeaderRow1.Cells.Add(tblheaderCell)
```

Now my event Checked/Unchecked work correctly ! I'm curious why if you don't use the tableHeaderRow the event on the first line below the head don't work for Unchecked (CheckBox) but Checked work.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need **AutoPostBack="True"** set on the CheckBox control

Comment: Nope, OP says *the Event is correctly fired but when I uncheck it, there are no event.*